# SQL case statement help on adding a comma separated string after the "then" clause

Tags: sql, case

I need some help with my query. Its the case statement thats causing an error.
The error is  Incorrect syntax near ',' and refers to the comma between the first Monday and Tuesday.
Is there a way to get this to work using square brackets or extra commas or something. I've tried a few different permutations of commas and brackets but its not working for me.
Thanks for helping!

```
`select calendar.dt from P left join C on  P.idC= C.idC
cross join calendar
where 
 and Pstartdate <= getdate() 
and PfinDate >= getDate()
and dayname in 
(case when duration = 1 and mon = 1 then 'Monday'
 when duration = 1 and tues = 1 then 'Tuesday'
 when duration = 1 and weds = 1 then 'Wednesday'
 when duration = 1 and thurs = 1 then 'Thursday'
 when duration = 1 and fri = 1 then 'Friday'
when duration = 2 and mon = 1 then ('Monday','Tuesday')
 when duration = 2 and tues = 1 then ('Tuesday','Wednesday')
 when duration = 2 and weds = 1 then ('Wednesday','Thursday')
 when duration = 2 and thurs = 1 then ('Thursday','Friday')
when duration = 3 and mon = 1 then ('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday')
 when duration = 3 and tues = 1 then ('Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday')
 when duration = 3 and weds = 1 then ('Wednesday','Thursday','Friday')
 when duration = 4 and mon = 1 then        ('Monday','Tuesday'',''Wednesday'',''Thursday')
 when duree = 4 and tues = 1 then ('Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday')
 when duree = 5 and mon = 1 then ('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday')
 end)
`
```

Comment: if you comment out the 3 lines before the end statement, does it work (for those conditions?).  You have too many quotes in the duration4/mon1 line, and duree instead of duration in the 2 lines following.

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily do this with a `case` statement.  Just use logic like this:

```
 (duration = 1 and ((mon = 1 and dayname = 'Monday') or
                    (tues = 1 and dayname = 'Tuesday') or
                    . . .
                   ) or
  duration = 2 and ((mon = 1 and dayname in ('Monday','Tuesday') or
                    . . .
                   )
  . . .
 )
```

However, I suspect that there is a simpler way to either structure your data or query it, to achieve what you want.

Comment: This worked great, thank you. Not so pretty a solution but a solution so job done for me!

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
(case when duration = 1 and mon = 1 then ('Monday')
 when duration = 1 and tues = 1 then ('Tuesday')
 when duration = 1 and weds = 1 then ('Wednesday')
 when duration = 1 and thurs = 1 then ('Thursday')
 when duration = 1 and fri = 1 then ('Friday')
when duration = 2 and mon = 1 then ('Monday','Tuesday')
 when duration = 2 and tues = 1 then ('Tuesday','Wednesday')
 when duration = 2 and weds = 1 then ('Wednesday','Thursday')
 when duration = 2 and thurs = 1 then ('Thursday','Friday')
when duration = 3 and mon = 1 then ('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday')
 when duration = 3 and tues = 1 then ('Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday')
 when duration = 3 and weds = 1 then ('Wednesday','Thursday','Friday')
 when duration = 4 and mon = 1 then        ('Monday','Tuesday'',''Wednesday'',''Thursday')
 when duree = 4 and tues = 1 then ('Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday')
 when duree = 5 and mon = 1 then ('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday')
 end)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `case` statement returns only a single value. There are any number of ways to do what you want, here is one requiring little alteration.

```
select  calendar.dt
from    P
left join C
    on  P.idC = C.idC
cross join calendar
where   Pstartdate <= getdate() 
    and PfinDate >= getDate()
    and 1 = case
        when duration = 1 and mon   = 1 and dayname = 'Monday' then 1
        when duration = 1 and tues  = 1 and dayname = 'Tuesday' then 1
        when duration = 1 and weds  = 1 and dayname = 'Wednesday' then 1
        when duration = 1 and thurs = 1 and dayname = 'Thursday' then 1
        when duration = 1 and fri   = 1 and dayname = 'Friday' then 1
        when duration = 2 and mon   = 1 and dayname in( 'Monday', 'Tuesday' ) then 1
        when duration = 2 and tues  = 1 and dayname in( 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday' ) then 1
        when duration = 2 and weds  = 1 and dayname in( 'Wednesday', 'Thursday' ) then 1
        when duration = 2 and thurs = 1 and dayname in( 'Thursday', 'Friday') then 1
        when duration = 3 and mon   = 1 and dayname in( 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday') then 1
        when duration = 3 and tues  = 1 and dayname in( 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday') then 1
        when duration = 3 and weds  = 1 and dayname in( 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday') then 1
        when duration = 4 and mon   = 1 and dayname in( 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday') then 1
        when duration = 4 and tues  = 1 and dayname in( 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday') then 1
        when duration = 5 and mon   = 1 and dayname in( 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday') then 1
            else 0
        end
```

Comment: That looks tidier. Yes, I could see that the case didn't like retuning two values as I was trying to do. But I was so deep into the data, if you know what I mean, I couldn't see any other way. Someone else's perspective is always good!